# How to make function return value for each row before going to the next row in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
lineups <- tibble::tribble(
                                                               ~lineupBefore,          ~playerOut,           ~playerIn,
  "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Kendrick Nunn",     "Kendrick Nunn",      "Goran Dragic",
                                                                          NA,   "Justise Winslow", "Derrick Jones Jr.",
                                                                          NA,    "Meyers Leonard",      "Kelly Olynyk",
                                                                          NA,       "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow",
                                                                          NA,       "Tyler Herro",   "Duncan Robinson",
                                                                          NA, "Derrick Jones Jr.",       "Bam Adebayo",
                                                                          NA,      "Goran Dragic",     "Kendrick Nunn",
                                                                          NA,   "Justise Winslow",       "Tyler Herro",
                                                                          NA,      "Kelly Olynyk",    "Meyers Leonard",
                                                                          NA,       "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow"
  )
```

Then, I create a column with:

```
lineups %>%
 mutate(lineupAfter = str_replace(lineupBefore, playerOut, playerIn))
```

which results in:

```
tibble::tribble(
                                                                 ~lineupBefore,          ~playerOut,           ~playerIn,                                                              ~lineupAfter,
    "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Kendrick Nunn",     "Kendrick Nunn",      "Goran Dragic", "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",
                                                                            NA,   "Justise Winslow", "Derrick Jones Jr.",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,    "Meyers Leonard",      "Kelly Olynyk",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,       "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,       "Tyler Herro",   "Duncan Robinson",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA, "Derrick Jones Jr.",       "Bam Adebayo",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,      "Goran Dragic",     "Kendrick Nunn",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,   "Justise Winslow",       "Tyler Herro",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,      "Kelly Olynyk",    "Meyers Leonard",                                                                        NA,
                                                                            NA,       "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow",                                                                        NA
    )
```

Now, I want to do the NA values in lineupBefore to be the previous value from lineupAfter. Then, the same function that created the lineupAfter column must be applied to the new values from lineupBefore. If I try to do it with mutate, it will only replace the values in the first NA row. So I would need the function to work on each row, turning it into something different than NA, before going on to the next row. I guess I need to use purrr to do it but I have no idea how. Any help would be appreciated!

Edit:

This is what the first 5 rows are expected to look like:

```
tibble::tribble(
                                                                  ~lineupBefore,        ~playerOut,           ~playerIn,                                                                      ~lineupAfter,
     "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Kendrick Nunn",   "Kendrick Nunn",      "Goran Dragic",         "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",
      "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic", "Justise Winslow", "Derrick Jones Jr.",       "Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",
    "Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",  "Meyers Leonard",      "Kelly Olynyk",         "Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Kelly Olynyk, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",
      "Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Kelly Olynyk, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",     "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow",     "Derrick Jones Jr., Justise Winslow, Kelly Olynyk, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",
  "Derrick Jones Jr., Justise Winslow, Kelly Olynyk, Tyler Herro, Goran Dragic",     "Tyler Herro",   "Duncan Robinson", "Derrick Jones Jr., Justise Winslow, Kelly Olynyk, Duncan Robinson, Goran Dragic"
  )
```

As you can see, row 2 of column lineupBefore would be equal to row 1 of column lineupAfter, row 3 of column lineupBefore would be equal to row 2 of column lineupAfter, and so on. 
Meanwhile, row 2 of lineupAfter would be the result of str_replace(lineupBefore, playerOut, playerIn) applied to row 2 of lineupBefore, and so on.

Comment: Can you show the expected column

Comment: Do you need `v1 <- c(first(lineups$lineupBefore), rep("", nrow(lineups) -1 )); for(i in 2:nrow(lineups)) v1[i] <- str_replace(v1[i-1], lineups$playerOut[i-1], lineups$playerIn[i-1])`

Comment: Just edited the question with the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a piped `{purrr}` style approach. What you're doing here is accumulating changes from one set to another set, so you want to use `purrr::accumulate` and `setdiff`.

I think it'll be a lot easier to make your `lineup*` columns list-columns, instead of strings like they are. That means storing a vector of names in each row of the column, not a single string with commas inside it.

Proceeding from your first `lineups` table:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lineups <- 
  tibble::tribble(
  ~lineupBefore,          ~playerOut,           ~playerIn,
  "Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonard, Tyler Herro, Kendrick Nunn",     "Kendrick Nunn",      "Goran Dragic",
  NA,   "Justise Winslow", "Derrick Jones Jr.",
  NA,    "Meyers Leonard",      "Kelly Olynyk",
  NA,       "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow",
  NA,       "Tyler Herro",   "Duncan Robinson",
  NA, "Derrick Jones Jr.",       "Bam Adebayo",
  NA,      "Goran Dragic",     "Kendrick Nunn",
  NA,   "Justise Winslow",       "Tyler Herro",
  NA,      "Kelly Olynyk",    "Meyers Leonard",
  NA,       "Bam Adebayo",   "Justise Winslow"
)

lineups_list <- 
  lineups %>% 
  mutate(lineupBefore = str_split(lineupBefore, ", "))

lineups_list
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 3
>    lineupBefore playerOut         playerIn         
>    <list>       <chr>             <chr>            
>  1 <chr [5]>    Kendrick Nunn     Goran Dragic     
>  2 <chr [1]>    Justise Winslow   Derrick Jones Jr.
>  3 <chr [1]>    Meyers Leonard    Kelly Olynyk     
>  4 <chr [1]>    Bam Adebayo       Justise Winslow  
>  5 <chr [1]>    Tyler Herro       Duncan Robinson  
>  6 <chr [1]>    Derrick Jones Jr. Bam Adebayo      
>  7 <chr [1]>    Goran Dragic      Kendrick Nunn    
>  8 <chr [1]>    Justise Winslow   Tyler Herro      
>  9 <chr [1]>    Kelly Olynyk      Meyers Leonard   
> 10 <chr [1]>    Bam Adebayo       Justise Winslow
> ```

So now you have a `lineupBefore` column where the first element is a length-5 vector, and all the length-1 vector rows are single `NA` values.

The function we want to do is take that first length-5 vector, and add the `playerIn` name to the vector sequentially (`c(initial_players, new_player)` over and over). If we had an infinite basketball game, that's what we'd have, just constantly adding players. `purrr::accumulate` will do just that, returning the results at every step.

But then we also want to take out the player from `playerOut` at each step. That's the same as `setdiff(current_players, removed_player)` over and over. In order to do both at the same time, we use `purrr::accumulate2`.

The function we pass to it sequentially operates on the args `..1`, `..2`, and `..3` where the previous step's result becomes the next step's `..1`. The first argument we pass in in `playerIn`, so that's the `..2` being added to the result every time. The second argument is `playerOut`, so that's the `..3` we're removing with `setdiff` every time. And we have to initialize it with the starting roster (`lineupBefore[[1]]`), otherwise it would just accumulate from an empty team with no players.

You can see what output you'd get with something like this:

```
x <- lineups_list$playerIn
y <- lineups_list$playerOut

accumulate2(
  x, y,  ~setdiff(c(..1, ..2), ..3), 
  .init = lineups_list$lineupBefore[[1]]
  )
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "Justise Winslow" "Bam Adebayo"     "Meyers Leonard"  "Tyler Herro"     "Kendrick Nunn"  
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "Justise Winslow" "Bam Adebayo"     "Meyers Leonard"  "Tyler Herro"     "Goran Dragic"   
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "Bam Adebayo"       "Meyers Leonard"    "Tyler Herro"       "Goran Dragic"      "Derrick Jones Jr."
>
> [[4]]
> [1] "Bam Adebayo"       "Tyler Herro"       "Goran Dragic"      "Derrick Jones Jr." "Kelly Olynyk"     
>
> [[5]]
> [1] "Tyler Herro"       "Goran Dragic"      "Derrick Jones Jr." "Kelly Olynyk"      "Justise Winslow"  
>
> [[6]]
> [1] "Goran Dragic"      "Derrick Jones Jr." "Kelly Olynyk"      "Justise Winslow"   "Duncan Robinson"  
>
> [[7]]
> [1] "Goran Dragic"    "Kelly Olynyk"    "Justise Winslow" "Duncan Robinson" "Bam Adebayo"    
>
> [[8]]
> [1] "Kelly Olynyk"    "Justise Winslow" "Duncan Robinson" "Bam Adebayo"     "Kendrick Nunn"  
>
> [[9]]
> [1] "Kelly Olynyk"    "Duncan Robinson" "Bam Adebayo"     "Kendrick Nunn"   "Tyler Herro"    
>
> [[10]]
> [1] "Duncan Robinson" "Bam Adebayo"     "Kendrick Nunn"   "Tyler Herro"     "Meyers Leonard" 
>
> [[11]]
> [1] "Duncan Robinson" "Kendrick Nunn"   "Tyler Herro"     "Meyers Leonard"  "Justise Winslow"
> ```

However, this is a list of length 11. That's because we started with a `.init` argument, so it's counted as one of the steps. You might notice then that the elements 2-11 are the ones you want for `lineupAfter`, and the elements 1-10 are the ones you want for `lineupBefore`. So you can use the same function to calculate both, you just need to cut off the first element or last element. (Side note, you could just use some version of `lead`/`lag` to offset one column from another, which would keep you from calculating these functions twice. But I left it that way to show their parallel structure.)

```
lineups_list_filled <- lineups_list %>% 
  mutate(
    lineupAfter = accumulate2(
      playerIn, playerOut, ~setdiff(c(..1, ..2), ..3),
      .init = lineupBefore[[1]]
    )[-1],                          # [] removes the head
    lineupBefore = accumulate2(
      playerIn, playerOut, ~setdiff(c(..1, ..2), ..3),
      .init = lineupBefore[[1]]
    )[-length(playerIn)]            # [] removes the last element
  )

lineups_list_filled
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 10 x 4
>    lineupBefore playerOut         playerIn          lineupAfter
>    <list>       <chr>             <chr>             <list>     
>  1 <chr [5]>    Kendrick Nunn     Goran Dragic      <chr [5]>  
>  2 <chr [5]>    Justise Winslow   Derrick Jones Jr. <chr [5]>  
>  3 <chr [5]>    Meyers Leonard    Kelly Olynyk      <chr [5]>  
>  4 <chr [5]>    Bam Adebayo       Justise Winslow   <chr [5]>  
>  5 <chr [5]>    Tyler Herro       Duncan Robinson   <chr [5]>  
>  6 <chr [5]>    Derrick Jones Jr. Bam Adebayo       <chr [5]>  
>  7 <chr [5]>    Goran Dragic      Kendrick Nunn     <chr [5]>  
>  8 <chr [5]>    Justise Winslow   Tyler Herro       <chr [5]>  
>  9 <chr [5]>    Kelly Olynyk      Meyers Leonard    <chr [5]>  
> 10 <chr [5]>    Bam Adebayo       Justise Winslow   <chr [5]>
> ```

If you look at `lineups_list_filled$lineupBefore` and `lineups_list_filled$lineupAfter`, you'll see that they match the correct elements of the length-11 list above. If you want to collapse them back down to a string, for printing, for example, you can always do something like:

```
lineups_list_filled %>% 
  mutate_all(
    ~map_chr(., ~paste(.x, collapse = ", "))
  )
```

P.S. This method only works if you have non-repeated elements, like individual players in a roster. If you were doing this with arbitrary integers, for example, you can't have 3 in there twice, because `setdiff` calls `unique` first. In that situation, you could construct your own version of `setdiff` that uses `match` and `which` and some error checking for edge cases.

Answer (score 3):

We can update it in a loop by assignment

```
v1 <- c(first(lineups$lineupBefore), rep("", nrow(lineups) -1 ))
for(i in 2:nrow(lineups)) v1[i] <- str_replace(v1[i-1],
          lineups$playerOut[i-1], lineups$playerIn[i-1])
lineups$lineupBefore <- v1
library(dplyr)
lineups %>%
     mutate(lineupAfter = lead(lineupBefore))
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   lineupBefore                                 playerOut     playerIn     lineupAfter                               
#   <chr>                                        <chr>         <chr>        <chr>                                     
# 1 Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonar… Kendrick Nunn Goran Dragic Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leon…
# 2 Justise Winslow, Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leonar… Justise Wins… Derrick Jon… Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Meyers Le…
# 3 Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Meyers Leon… Meyers Leona… Kelly Olynyk Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Kelly Oly…
# 4 Derrick Jones Jr., Bam Adebayo, Kelly Olyny… Bam Adebayo   Justise Win… Derrick Jones Jr., Justise Winslow, Kelly…
# 5 Derrick Jones Jr., Justise Winslow, Kelly O… Tyler Herro   Duncan Robi… Derrick Jones Jr., Justise Winslow, Kelly…
# ...
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do this inside a dplyr chain using purrr?